# numbering permutations with repeated items

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I want to number each permutation of ${1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}$ (4 ones and 8 zeros) with a number. There are $\frac{12\cdot 11\cdot 10 \cdot 9}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1} = 495$ permutations. I want something like this

$$(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)\equiv 0$$
$$(1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)\equiv 1$$
$$(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)\equiv 494$$

I found a way, but this is a really long algorithm.

For example $(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)$:

There are $\frac{11\cdot 10 \cdot 9}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1} = 165$ permutations, which start with $(1,\dots)$.

There are $\frac{9\cdot 8}{2\cdot 1} + \frac{8\cdot 7}{2\cdot 1} = 36+28 = 64$ permutations, which start with $(0,1,1,\dots)$ or $(0,1,0,1,\dots)$.

So the number for $(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)$ would be $165+64 = 229$.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: See the section on "numbering permutations" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation and if you find what you need there then come back here to post a summary as an answer to your question.